# How to change the unicode strings in a pandas column of objects that should be converted to int64?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, unicode

I have to make a pd.merge of two dataframes on a `siren` column and I need to transform a column of type `object` to type `int64`.

```
>df_bdc['siren'] = df_bdc['siren'].astype(int)
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

So I tried with float but I got back

```
df_bdc['siren'] = df_bdc['siren'].astype(float)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\u200e325559193'.
```

Then I tried to suppress the string `\u200e` but it returns that `can't decode bytes ...`.

```
df_bdc['siren'].str.replace('\u200e','')

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-4: truncated \uXXXX escape (1328494262.py, line 1)
```

So I also tried dropping nans but I got an invalid literal issue:

```
>df_bdc['siren'] = df_bdc['siren'].dropna().astype(int)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\u200e325559193'
```

Comment: Notice that your second attempt, with `.replace`, yielded a SyntaxError, which makes me suspect that you made a mistake typing it in.

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.removeprefix.html?highlight=removeprefix#pandas.Series.str.removeprefix

```
df_bdc['siren'].str.removeprefix('\u200e')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I have `AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'removeprefix'`

Comment: Could you upload the data to check?